# numerical precision in recursive functions

Tags: c++, precision, numerical

I am puzzled, when evaluating the following function it produces number till F(0.8, 172, 1), but when I increase 172 to 173, the result becomes infinite. I suspect there is a numerical precision problem?

```
double F(double d, int c, int t) {
    // base cases
    if ((c==1 && t==1) || (c==0 && t==0))
        return 1.;
    if (c==0 || t==0)
        return 0.;
    if (t>c)
        return 0.;
    return F(d,c-1,t-1) + (c-1 - t*d)*F(d,c-1,t);
}
```

Comment: can you explain what does this do?

Comment: I do not think there is a precision issue here. The reason is because the double is not being used as a condition anywhere in this function. Perhaps the real bug is somewhere else?

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/fp/  So you are actually right, it's problem with `double` numerical precision (in a sense it's limited in every way - of course, you can put only so many numbers into 64 bits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what your function is supposed to do, but given the arguments: `F(0.8, 172, 1)` the return value is `4.41861e+306` which is just short of the maximum value a `double` can represent:

```
// 1.79769e+308
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::max() << std::endl;
```

When `172` is replaced with `173`, the return value exceeds the maximum value a `double` can represent and becomes positive infinity. This is made clear by changing the return type of `F` to be `long double` which results in the value `7.56466e+308`

Comment: @bansi, The number went off to the right so far that at first I thought you were pointing out a bug before I realized `7.56466e+308` is just that big, ha ha. `std::cout` gives scientific notation

Comment: `long double` isn't necessarily wider than `double`